# Docker usr/bin/env: ‘bash\r’: No such file or directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

Hi I am completely new to docker and run into the dreaded

> Docker usr/bin/env: ‘bash\r’: No such file or directory issue.

I understand there are number of answers posted here but none of them were able to help me as I think I need bit more insight into what script is causing this issue so that I can change the file format to UNIX from DOS.

I am unable to start airflow webserver because of this issue but what is the underlying script that is causing this issue?
could it be my entrypoint.sh script? I have tried to replace this file but to no avail.
Please help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)

Comment: "What script is causing the issue" -- how are we supposed to know that? You aren't showing us any information about what scripts you _have_ in the first place. Yes, it _could_ be your `entrypoint.sh`, but it could be any other script you're putting in the container too; we have no way of knowing from only what you've included in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many days of trawling through multiple sources online, I finally managed to run the whole thing in WSL2 Ubuntu system on my Windows machine.
Now that it is up an running to me WSL seems like a godsend to side step problems like this!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using dos2unix on the offending file? that'll fix the Windows encoding https://dos2unix.sourceforge.io/

Comment: I need to find out what that offending file is. I am sorry if it is a daft question but I am using someone's docker-compose file and it does not seem to be triggering any other script apart from the default entrypoint.sh

Comment: just run it on the whole dir.

Comment: I have tried dos2unix and unix2dos on all files in the directly but still getting same error